# Angular 6/RxJS How to unsubcribe using takeUntil() and route params

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to do something that I find too tricky. I'm trying to unsubscribe from a `Subscription` using `takeUntil` and waiting for the route params to emit a change.

Here is the tricky part: I need to set the `takeUntil` inside the route params `subscribe`. It should be something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.autoMethodSubscription = interval(5000).pipe(takeUntil(this.route.params)).subscribe(() => { this.autoMethod(); });
    });
}
```

The `autoMethodSubscription` does not work because it insta unsubscribes I think.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is your overall goal here? To do some action when the route params change? Why not simply pipe the `this.route.params` and subscribe to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `skip` the first one.

```
interval(5000).pipe(
   takeUntil(
      this.route.params
         .pipe(skip(1))
)).subscribe(() => //...
```

Or you can `filter` the `route.params` changes to specify *what* kind of route changes will force unsubscribing.

Or you can use the most common pattern, unsubscribe on destroy.

What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Skipping the first one was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Be careful, skipping the first one will break if no parameters are given to the route. If route has 1+ parameter: the subscribe triggers twice. If route has no parameter it only triggers once.